# Language detect in Joomla php

Tags: php, joomla

I need to add php code in a Joomla backend file to display different link depending to the selected language.

I need to display link1 if language selected is english, while link2 if language selected is german

I'm using this php code, but I not understand the error:

```
<?php
    $menu = JSite::getMenu();

    if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault( 'en-GB' ))
    {
        <li>
            <a href="link1" class="btn btn-primary">
                <?php echo JText::_('OSM_ALTERNATIVE'); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li>
            <a href="link2" class="btn btn-primary">
                <?php echo JText::_('OSM_ALTERNATIVE'); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    }
?>
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have not used a closing PHP tag before your HTML.

Secondly, you are detecting the frontpage of your Joomla site, not the language. Try using the following:

```
<?php
    $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
    $tag  = $lang->getTag();

    if ($tag == 'en-GB')
    { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="link1" class="btn btn-primary">
                <?php echo JText::_('OSM_ALTERNATIVE'); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
  <?php } else { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="link2" class="btn btn-primary">
                <?php echo JText::_('OSM_ALTERNATIVE'); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
  <?php } 
?>
```

Comment: @Niko - Glad it worked. Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick icon on the left